# strange numbers width in nextjs image custom loader

Tags: next.js

I use Nextjs image custom loader but it has an argument named **width** I checked my console it is a different number (strange numbers like : 203 793 3840  ) every time
I can't understand what it really is?
how can I customize these numbers?
how are these numbers useful?

Comment: That'll correspond to the width of the `next/image`. Its value is either what you specified directly on each image, OR if you're using `layout: fill` it'll be based on `imageSizes` and `deviceSizes` in your `next.config.js`.